# How can I transfer music from one iphone to another if it has NOT BEEN purchased from iTunes (ie., songs that were put on there from cd's I own etc.)

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

Is there a way to transfer songs from one iphone to a new iphone that were NOT purchased from iTunes?  I am talking about songs that were from cd's that I or my son own.  They are on my old phone but will not transfer to the new phone because they weren't iTunes purchases.  If this is a "feature" of an Apple iPhone, I can understand peoples frustrations.

Comment: How did you get the songs onto your old phone in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Only one "library" or subset of one library can exist on a single *mobile*  device. You can manage your non-iTunes purchased music and move it to your device through iTunes.  But you can not move it from device to device, or device back to PC.  Why not?  Doing so could promote piracy of songs (media).

You can only normally transfer music in one direction: iTunes -> Device. The reason for this is to limit music sharing, this follows the model apple created to satisfy the recording industries demands as apple demanded an end to DRM encrypted files.

Additionally, related but not part of your question, you are essentially prohibited from transferring songs from someone else's iTunes library directly to your phone.  If you attempt to do so it will warn you that you are about to replace the existing *library* on the device with a new one, meaning all song currently on the device will be wiped if you continue.

If the original iTunes files are not available on the computer, you can't just transfer them from the device back to iTunes. There are however apps in the app store that allow you to transfer music back to a PC, at that point you can use iTunes to put it on the new phone. I can't personally suggest any of these as I've never used them. Google the term *iphone transfer music to pc* to learn more and read reviews.

Another method if the original CD's are still available you could use iTunes to re-rip them to iTunes on the computer, and then move them to the new phone.

Apple also sells an add-on called [iTunes Match](https://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/) that will allow you to download songs in your ripped library directly to your device.  However this service isn't a necessity at all, it just adds convenience over managing your library directly thru iTunes.

This is *my opinion* on the subject, but if a person understands how the system works, it's not hard to follow the rules, but it does seem confusing when a person is replacing their phone and doesn't know the rules.  I would also rather have this system in place than DRM encoded music downloads from the app store.

Comment: Hi Tyson -- The problem is that when I do a backup TO iTunes, it will not back up the songs that were not purchased THROUGH iTunes, even though they are in my "iTunes Library" on the phone.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Carole Correct. You can not transfer in that direction.  The reason for this is to limit music sharing, this follows the model apple created to satisfy the recording industries demands as apple demanded an end to DRM encrypted files.  I guessing that you no longer have the files on the computer, so you can't just transfer them to the new phone using iTunes.  With that thought in mind, there are apps in the app store that allow you to transfer music back to a PC, at that point you can use iTunes to put it on the new phone. I can't personally suggest but google "iphone transfer music to pc".

Comment: @Carole another option if you still have the CD's is to re-rip the music to iTunes.

Comment: Answer edited to reflect your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution with the already described way of re-importing transferred playlists and songs from the device to a Mac to put them onto another device. That includes a 3rd party software.

When I get a new MacBook Pro at work, I use the software "iExplorer" to transfer all my contact data from my iPhone 5 back into the new Macbook Pro. That also does work with images for iPhoto and even with the whole music library including the playlists. 
Nice thing with this software is, you can *select* what to transfer and you have the complete control over your device, you can even save back the apps and their preferences. For that complete set of features I did not mind to pay $35.

As I recommended this tool multiple times before in postings I have to state that I am not affiliated with MacroPlant in any way, but I really love that thing and I can only recommend it! :)

With onboard magic it is hardly possible to do the required task.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can with the help of itunes. Add songs into iTunes library and connect your new phone with computer, and then transfer the musis songs to it. But you need make sure these songs are accepted by your phone, what I means is they are M4A file type, otherwise, they cannot be added into either iTunes or your phone.